# How to query a specified row from each group

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, row

I have a table of products and each record has the price it was sold at, which can vary

```
+-------+-----+----+
|Product|Price|Date|
+-------+-----+----+
|a      |2    |A   |
+-------+-----+----+
|a      |3    |B   |
+-------+-----+----+
|a      |4    |C   |
+-------+-----+----+
|a      |1    |D   |
+-------+-----+----+
|b      |10   |E   |
+-------+-----+----+
|b      |15   |F   |
+-------+-----+----+
|b      |20   |G   |
+-------+-----+----+
```

I want to select Max price row group by [Product], how to query? Result I want:

```
+-------+-----+----+
|Product|Price|Date|
+-------+-----+----+
|a      |4    |C   |
+-------+-----+----+
|b      |20   |G   |
+-------+-----+----+
```

I tried

```
SELECT Product, Max(Price) as Price FROM TableName GROUP BY Product
```

but it does not get the [Date] column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always use an CTE if this is on SQL server.

```
WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT Product, MAX(Price) AS Price
FROM TableName
GROUP BY Product
)
SELECT CTE.Product, CTE.Price, T.Date
FROM CTE
INNER JOIN
TableName T ON CTE.Product = T.Product AND CTE.Price = T.Price
```

However, there could be other viable options that are performing better, that you will have to verify yourself :) Also I have not taken into account that you could have a product with same price on two records (doesn't say from description that it should be considered)....

Comment: Assuming that the price field could be decimal or money, it's not a good idea to join on such field.

Comment: Thanks, it works well and only takes about 2 seconds to query among 2 million records in SQL Server 2005.

Comment: What if I want to select the top two records in each group?

Answer (score 1):

Try this-

```
SELECT
    PRODUCT
    ,PRICE
    ,DATE
FROM
 (  SELECT
        PRODUCT
        ,PRICE
    ,   DATE
        , RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY PRODUCT ORDER BY PRICE DESC) AS RANKED_PRICE
    FROM TableName
) RANKED_DATA
WHERE RANKED_PRICE IN (1,2,3....N)
```

What we are doing is ranking the rows partitioned by product and in descending order of the price. Then we select the rows which have rank 1 to get the result you need.

Comment: Thanks, it works well and takes about 5 seconds to query among 2 million records in SQL Server 2005.

Comment: @Nature - Modified my answer above in reply to your question - if you want to select multiple records - just keep on adding the ranks. If the rank exists, records will get selected. Note that selecting few more records will definitely slow it a bit.

Answer (score 0):

```
select Product, Price, Date
from   TableName p1
where  p1.Price >= all ( 
    select p2.Price
    from   TableName p2
    where  p2.Product = p1.Product )
```

Comment: Thanks, it can work but the efficient is unacceptable. There is 2 million records in the table and it takes about five minutes to query. I use SQL Server 2005.